# How to create token using Identity Server 4 for external authentication provider

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, identity, asp.net-core-identity

I have created an application using the ID4 library where two types of users can log in.

1. External user - These user's information is stored in AspNet membership DB.
2. Internal user - These user's information is stored in Azure Active Directory.

**Implementation Background:** I have integrated Microsoft AAD for external authentication once the user validated from AAD and execute applications callback then we are fetching required claims from Microsoft AccessToken and creating new ID4's AccessToken.

**Requirement:** Now my requirement is to create AccessToken without any user interaction (using [password](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore2/topics/grant_types.html) grant type), to get access token I am using [/connect/token](http:///connect/tokens) endpoint which is working perfectly fine for **external users** but the only problem is I can't use this endpoint to get token for **Internal users** as those user's information stored in Azure Active Directory and not in AspNet membership DB. So whenever I hit /connect/token endpoint it will validates user's details in AspNet DB and always returns the "invalid_username_or_password" response.

**What I am thinking:**

I can create a new custom endpoint that will validate the internal user using LDAP or GraphAPI. Once user validation succeeds I will create ID4's AccessToken (Similar as [/connect/token](http:///connect/token) endpoint). Please correct me if I misunderstood something.

Any lead/help would be appreciated. Drop a comment if you want to understand it in detail or want to brainstorm with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) . In your scenario , client will send user's credentials to identity server , possible with parameter shows which identity provider(Azure AD/local database) user wants to use . If user want to use Azure AD , you can directly send credentials to Azure AD and create IDS's tokens based on ID token returned from Azure AD .

But as document shows this flow is not recommended :

> Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most scenarios, more secure alternatives are available and recommended. This flow requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries risks which are not present in other flows. You should only use this flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

And this flow has limits in Azure AD :

> - The Microsoft identity platform endpoint only supports ROPC for Azure AD tenants, not personal accounts. This means that you must use a tenant-specific endpoint (https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId_or_Name}) or the organizations endpoint.
> - Personal accounts that are invited to an Azure AD tenant can't use ROPC.
> - Accounts that don't have passwords can't sign in through ROPC. For this scenario, we recommend that you use a different flow for your app instead.
> - If users need to use multi-factor authentication (MFA) to log in to the application, they will be blocked instead.
> - ROPC is not supported in hybrid identity federation scenarios (for example, Azure AD and ADFS used to authenticate on-premises accounts). If users are full-page redirected to an on-premises identity providers, Azure AD is not able to test the username and password against that identity provider. Pass-through authentication is supported with ROPC, however.